# Duplicate row detected during DML action Row Values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Each of our messages has a unique id and several attributes; the final result should combine all of these attributes into a single message. We tried using snowflake merge, but it's not working as expected. In the first run, we used row number and partition to determine unique records, and we inserted them. In the second run, we considered updating more than one record, but we received the error message "Error 3:Duplicate row detected during DML action Row Values: \n".

Session ERROR ON NONDETERMINISTIC MERGE=FALSE was tried, however the outcome might not be reliable or consistent.

We tried javascript deep merge, however the volume was really high and there were performance problems.

**Sample code below:**

```
create or replace table test1 (Job_Id VARCHAR, RECORD_CONTENT VARIANT);
create or replace table test2 like test1;


insert into test1(JOB_ID, RECORD_CONTENT) select 1,parse_json('{
            "customer": "Aphrodite",
            "age": 32,
            "orders": {"product": "socks","quantity": 4, "price": "$6", "attribute1" : "a1"}                   
 }');
 
 
insert into test1(JOB_ID, RECORD_CONTENT) select 1,parse_json('{
            "customer": "Aphrodite",
            "age": 32,
            "orders": {"product": "shoe", "quantity": 2, "brand" : "Woodland","attribute2" : "a2"}
                        
 }');
 
 insert into test1(JOB_ID, RECORD_CONTENT) select 1,parse_json('{
            "customer": "Aphrodite",
            "age": 32,
            "orders": {"product": "shoe polish","brand" : "Helios", "attribute3" : "a3" }
                        
 }');


merge into test2 t2 using (
  select * from (select
    row_number() over(partition by JOB_ID order by JOB_ID desc) as rno, JOB_ID, RECORD_CONTENT
    from test1) where rno>1) t1 on   //1. first run - unique values inserted using "=1" ->  Successfully inserted unique values
                                     //2. second run - updating attributes using ">1"  -> Duplicate row detected during DML action Row Values
t1.JOB_ID = t2.JOB_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET t2.JOB_ID = t1.JOB_ID,
t2.RECORD_CONTENT = t1.RECORD_CONTENT
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (JOB_ID, RECORD_CONTENT) VALUES (t1.JOB_ID, t1.RECORD_CONTENT)

Expected Output:-
select * from test2;
 select parse_json('{
            "customer": "Aphrodite",
            "age": 32,
            "orders": {"product": "shoe polish","quantity": 2, "brand" : "Helios","price": "$6", 
                        "attribute1" : "a1","attribute2" : "a2","attribute3" : "a3" }
 }');
```

Comment: Updating semi-structured data in Snowflake needs to use the `object_delete` and `object_insert` functions (unless you're using javascript, which you tried). However, there's another problem here. The expected output shows `"shoe polish"` should be the `"product"`, but there's no guarantee the merge will perform in the order in which the rows were inserted into the table. Setting aside merge for now, how many rows do you need to insert/update this way? How fast does the process need to complete? Do the updates need to be in a particular order? If so, how does the process get that order?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, 
But the problem here object_delete, object_insert knows the key right?  
  In our case all are dyanamic key, we don't have a key is fixed each of the messages dynamically changed. 
how many rows do you need to insert/update this way?
  approx 8k to 10K per min 
How fast does the process need to complete? 
  realtime ingestion so we are expecting to completed within a min 8k to 10k. 
 Do the updates need to be in a particular order? 
       We have a date column to order and updates.